# High Voltage Hysteresis Comparator Design

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, analog, integrated-circuit

I am working on a control circuit which requires design of Hysteresis Comparator circuit. The voltage level are quite high for which I am getting confused as how to replicate these accurately. I have limited knowledge over linear integrated circuits but I recollected some theory and designed hysteresis comparator using feedback on non-inverting terminal; but for lesser voltage level. Below is the characteristic curve for comparator I require for your reference.

[image]

There is a 48 V DC reference voltage available and the hysteresis lower and higher thresholds are 54 V and 57 V respectively.The input voltage won't go beyond 60V. 2 % accuracy in the threshold values is acceptable. **Please provide possible design solution for the requirement**

I understand that these level have to be brought down to normal operating voltage levels for an Op-Amp. But I might have stuck with some incorrect parameter. Need some expertise on analog circuit design. I would love to get a clear idea where I am getting confused.

Comment: *"I would love to get a clear idea where I am getting confused."* So would we.. perhaps you could tell us?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, you'll get better answers

Comment: @Trevor_G: You take care of solution, I'll take care of my confusion :)

Comment: @laptop2d: I edited the question

Comment: If you re-read your question you did not actually ask what you are confused about...

Comment: As few as two BJTs with appropriate VCEO and a few resistors could achieve the accuracy requirements, even with typical BJT variations in beta and saturation currents. But you've provided NO information at all on what Vout = HI happens to be.

Comment: @jonk: That High should be enough to run a MOSFET.. say 15V.

Comment: @PHRJT sure. Plenty of headroom. Have at it.

Answer (score 1):

> The voltage level are quite high for which I am getting confused as
>   how to replicate these accurately

Yes, they are a bit high so I would divide the input voltage down to something more manageable. Maybe a 10:1 resistor divider is something like what you want to convert 57 volts to 5.7 volts. Then you are in the right sort of territory.

However, you haven't said how high the input voltage could reach but assuming the maximum input voltage was 100 volts, a 10:1 divider is still reasonable for a comparator operating from a +15 volt rail.

But you haven't said how low the input voltage could go so if it is -100 volts you'll need a +/- 15 volt supply rail for you comparator.

You haven't specified accuracy i.e. it should switch positive for a voltage between 56 volts and 58 volts, so you need to consider this.

Once you have your limits and accuracy required you can start the design process proper. You can use one comparator but, if you need good and accurate independent control of both thresholds I would suggest two comparators and D type flip flop as your starting point.

One comparator triggers on the high level and one on the low level. The high-level comparator clocks "1" into the flip flop and the low-level comparator resets the flip flop.

Again, accuracy might be very important so, to generate the trigger threshold voltages you might want to use a precision voltage reference of 10 volts and potential dividers to produce upper and lower threshold voltages.

That is as much design I intend to do. The rest is for you to figure out.

Comment: LOL that's a lot of answer for no actual question :) +1 for patience.

Comment: @Trevor_G there is just no pleasing some folk LOL